# Android project structure for RC, Lite and Full app

Tags: android, google-play

I am planning an app for Android Marketplace.

First I want to release it for public testing as a free RC, to gather some feedback before I publish the Full app as a paid app. When RC is replaced by Full version I will publish a free Lite edition with some limitations.

The plan is to add a basic set of features without any limitations to the RC

Later on there will be

- A Full paid version with more features
- A Lite free version with same features as Full but with certain limitations.

I am looking for some advice on how to plan my project structure to avoid a lot of refactoring/moving of code as the application evolves.

Does something like this look reasonable ?

- A MAIN branch
- RC free app is derived from MAIN branch and is published to Market when ready
- When RC lifecycle ends, all changes from RC are merged into MAIN branch and RC branch is discontinued. RC app is also withdrawn from Market now.
- Lite free app is derived from MAIN branch, some limitations are applied to the Lite branch
- MAIN branch is now the branch for Full paid app. When new releases of the Full app are ready, changes are merged into the Lite branch so new features are added without any of the limitations removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem sometime ago, I decided to go with following structure. (I have an app with LITE / PAID edition).

I use a **single** codebase for both edition and I can do this thanks to maven.
With it I can just build the target version I need.

My Maven (pom.xml) is so configured that it creates a total new source-base, refactor package name, change AndroidManifest, replace icons, replace properties file, build and sign with the right key the APK all with a single command-line:

```
mvn install -Dedition=lite -P release
```

I think this is a good solution, the only drawback is that requires some work to configure your pom.xml right (especially if you don't know maven well).

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't know Maven very well but that seems to be a good way of handling it

Comment: You may also try the new build system: Gradle for Android, here a quick introduction: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/using-the-new-build-system

Answer (score 0):

If you're (more) familiar/comfortable with [Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html), setting up a library project and two dependent projects (lite, full) might be another way to go. Details at [firstlightassociates](http://www.firstlightassociates.co.uk/blog/2011/software/android-software/managing-free-and-paid-android-applications-2/) and [donnfelker](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/08/05/howto-android-full-and-lite-versions/).

- `com.example.myapp` - Android *Library* with all code and a runtime check on the package name to switch on/off specific functionality.
- `com.example.myapp.full` - Android Application. Any *full* version specific assets.
- `com.example.myapp.lite` - Android Application. Any *lite* version specific assets.